# Choose fields when try to inherit template in Odoo

Tags: python, templates, inheritance, tree, odoo

I try to display only 3 fields come from another template in odoo.

My pb is I inherit all the fields of products_group.py

I need just only that.
- customers_group_id
- price_group_view
- products_model_group

I tried some solution but I have always the same pb;

I do that :

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv, orm
from openerp.tools.translate import _
customers_group_id
class product_template(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    _description = "Product Template"

    _columns = {
                ......    
                'products_group_id_products': fields.one2many('products.group','customers_group_id', 'Products Group'),
                }

    class products_group(orm.Model):
        _inherit = 'products.group'
        # in comment, the result is the same    
        #    _columns = {
        #       'customers_group_id': fields.integer('Customer group Id', size=20, help='id of customers group'),
        #       'products_model_group': fields.char('Product model group', size=30, help='Model'),
        #       'price_group_view': fields.boolean('Price group view', default='1', help='Display Price Group View'),
        #       'products_group_view': fields.boolean('Product Group View', default='1', help='Display Group View'),
        #       'orders_group_view': fields.boolean('Display Order process', default='1', help='Display order Group View'),
        #    }
        #_order = 'sequence'
```

My products_group.py

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class products_group(orm.Model):
    _name = 'products.group'

    _columns = { 
        'customers_group_id': fields.integer('Customer group Id', size=20, help='id of customers group'),
        'customers_group_price': fields.float('Customers group Price', size=70, help='Price of the product group'),
        'products_id': fields.integer('Product Id', size=5, help="Id product must be unique"),
        'products_price': fields.float('Products_price',size=70, help='price of the product'),
        'price_group_view': fields.boolean('Price group view', default='1', help='Display Price Group View'),
        'products_group_view': fields.boolean('Product Group View', default='1', help='Display Group View'),
        'orders_group_view': fields.boolean('Display Order process', default='1', help='Display order Group View'),
        'products_model_group': fields.char('Product model group', size=30, help='Product model'),
        'products_quantity_unit_id_group': fields.integer('product Quantity Unit group', help='Default quantity for this group'),
        'products_quantity_fixed_group': fields.integer('product quanty Fixed', help='Default quantity for this group'),
    }
```

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <openerp>
        <data>
            <record model="ir.ui.view" id="template_product_form_view">
                <field name="name">product.template_product_test</field>
                <field name="model">product.template</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/> <!-- external_id -->
                <field name="priority" eval="16"/>

                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="My product">
                        <group col="4" colspan="4" string="General">
                         ....
                        </group>


                       <separator string="Groups Price B2B"/>
// My page display all my fields ofproducts.group and not the 3
                       <field name="products_group_id_products" />


                    </page>
                  </notebook>
                </field>
         </record>
    </data> 
</openerp>
```

Result on my products groups

```
customer group id    products id    products model group  
1                      1               model1
2                      1               model2
1                      3               model3
2                      3               model4
```

Result on my products template for my product id = 1 that I must display in tree view

```
customer group id    products id    products model group  
1                      1               model1
2                      1               model2
```

Customer group id is in relation with another table for example (but it's for later)

1 = resellers

2 = little resellers

There the solution

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv, orm
from openerp.tools.translate import _
customers_group_id
class product_template(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    _description = "Product Template"

     _columns = {
             ......    
             'products_group_id_products': fields.one2many('products.group', 'products_id', 'Products Group'),
       }

    class products_group(orm.Model):
    _inherit = 'products.group'

    _columns = {
        'sequence' : fields.integer('Sequence', help="Assigns the priority to the list of product groups."),
        'customers_group_id': fields.many2one('customers.group', 'Customer group Id', help='id of customers group'), 
        'products_model_group': fields.char('Product model group', size=30, help='Model'),
        'products_id': fields.integer('Product Id', size=5, help="Id product must be unique"),
         .....
    }

    _order = 'sequence'

    _defaults = {
      'sequence': 1,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Table `product_template` and `products_group` are set wrong relationship. According to the `one2many` we need to set that class of `many2one`

UPDATE:

try with these changes in class `products_group`:

```
'products_id': fields.many2one('product.template', 'Product Id', help="Id product must be unique"),
```

EDIT:

for xml side:

```
<separator string="Groups Price B2B"/>
<field name="products_group_id_products">
    <!-- place here field that how many you want like -->
    <field name="customers_group_id"/>
    <field name="price_group_view"/>
    <field name="products_model_group"/>
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes work, but it's not exactly that I want, I try to do the same thing like supplier in product. In class products_group, I need to take some fields and to have on my product page a result in function on the same  id of product and products_group.

Comment: try with updated answer. now you will get only three field in product

Comment: Hello, look the table above, I think you understand more thant I try to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I found a solution, not perfect because it write all fields but it work. You can see above.

Comment: okay I'm updating my answer too as per your code now it will work

Comment: Hi Odedra, I don't see your modification, need glasses ? :)

Comment: UPDATE string is added into answer and below line is changed